# TDD is a top-bottom or bottom-top design?

Tags: tdd

In my memory, most people told me I should design from top to bottom. If I want to implement a web page, I should image or draw this page on paper and then divide it into some functionality. For each functionality, I try design the external API, and implement their inside respectively.

But in TDD, they say I should consider a very very small functionality(a method?) first, write its test, fail, implement it and pass test. Composing them is the last step. I can't image how it gets good API.

And most strangely, they say TDD is not only unit tests and also function tests. I think it means top-bottom. If there is a functionality A composed of methods B, C and D. Because of TDD I write the function test for A first. But... B, C, D are all unimplemented. Should I use three stubs? If B depends on other three methods?

I used TDD to write some small programs. But when I striked an application with GUI, I got stuck.

Comment: Most important statement in this question: "I can't imagine how it gets good API".  You can't imagine it, because all you would be doing is imagining it, because you haven't done it.  Do it, and report back.  Don't speculate.  Do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been heavily writing rspec tests for my rails projects keeping a ratio of about 1:1.6 between code/tests. I never really had an issue of what to write first or what it depends on. If the method A that i want to write consists of B and C, then i would first implement B and C, again using the proper testing. To me the sequence is not so important as long as the tests are good and precise.

So, I don't really use stubs the way you describe it, but only if the functionality is already there and i just want to bypass/circumvent it.

BTW, it is considered a top-down approach. This is an excerpt from Rspec Book :

> If you ask experienced software
>   delivery folks why they run a project
>   like that, front-loading it with all
>   the planning and analysis, then getting into the detailed design and
>   programming, and only really integrating and testing it at the end, they
>   will gaze into the distance, looking
>   older than their years, and patiently
>   explain that this is to mitigate
>   against the exponential cost of
>   change—the principle that introducing
>   a change or discovering a defect
>   becomes exponentially more expensive
>   the later you discover it. The
>   top-down approach seems the only
>   sensible way to hedge against the
>   possibility of discovering a defect
>   late in the day.

Comment: My main question is: when do you write test of A? Before B and C pass their tests or after?

Comment: Personally, only after B and C pass their tests. It's kinda natural. For instance, to test a controller in rails, you first need the logic of the models, being B and C. The controller test, A, uses B, C methods after they are implemented.

Comment: This order of writing tests also makes it easier to know (if your tests for B and C are sufficiently good) when you can move to working on A, because B and C are done for the moment – your test system says “pass.”

Comment: But how do you know the existences of B and C? Do you design rough implement of A, figure out that you need B and C, red-green-refator them, write test of A, and then implement A?

Comment: Exactly, that is the idea. First things first :) Everything feels safer this way.

Comment: I doubt if I really understand. But I will try it. Accept.

Answer (score 2):

Since TDD starts with what you can see from the outside (of whatever item you are working on at the moment), I'm not sure how it could qualify as bottom-up.

Taking TDD to the extreme (e.g., as in XP, aka extreme programming), you would certainly start from the end-user perspective, and only ever write as much code as you need to pass the tests created so far. If you find yourself starting with the tests for some internal function before reaching the point where the higher-level tests (plus good design for the code you are writing to make those tests pass) require this routine, you are working on some other paradigm, not strict TDD – because there was no test telling you to write that method in the first place. Not that this is necessarily a bad thing, but any problems you have with that is not really one of the TDD methodology.

For GUI programming, of course, you have the standard problem of automating tests, even before you created code. I only know of good tools for web apps for that; if you have good pointers on this topic in the desktop case, I'd sure love to see them.

Comment: After reading SpyrosP's answer I thought I had gotten it. But I didn't again. If I haven't written some internal function, how can I test the external ones which depend on them? Stubs or not?

Comment: In the XP world, sure, stub all day long. I haven't got the books around here, but IIRC, they even introduce TDD by writing some test like `square(5)==25` and then just implement `int square(int) { return 25; }`, because that is the simplest code to make the test pass. As I said, that is TDD taken to an extreme, which may not be the right thing for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's top down. Say I had a single PDF that had 4 distinct documents in it and I was writing software to split them into 4 individual documents instead of a single document, the first test I would probably write is:

```
// Note: Keeping this very abstract
@Test
public void splitsDocumentsAccordingToDocumentType() {
   List docs = new DocumentProcessor().split(new SinglePdfWithFourDocs());
   assertEquals(4, docs());
   ...
}
```

I would consider the `DocumentProcessor.split()` method to be similar to "A" in your example. I could now implement the entire algorithm within the single method `split` and make the tests pass. I don't even need "B" or "C" right? Knowing that you're a good developer and you cringe at the thought of that 1500 line method you would start to look for ways to restructure your code to a more suitable design. Maybe you see that two additional objects (responsibilities) could be split out of this code:

1) Parsing the contents of the file to find the individual documents and
2) Reading and writing of the document from the file system

Let's tackle #1 first. Use a couple of "Extract Method" refactorings to localize code related to the parsing of the contents then an "Extract Class" refactoring, pulling out those methods into a class named, say `DocumentParser`. This could be analagous to "B" in your example. If you'd like, you could move tests related to document parsing from your `DocumentProcessorTest` to a new `DocumentParserTest` and mock or stub the `DocumentParser` in the `DocumentProcessorTest`.

For #2 it's pretty much lather, rinse, repeat and you'll end up with something like a `DocumentSerializer` class, AKA "C". You can mock this as well in your `DocumentProcessorTest` and you now have no file I/O and have test driven a component that has two additional collaborators without having to design your entire class (with individual methods). Notice that we took an "outside in" approach, which really enables the refactoring.

Thanks